# Conditional output of dynamic text in a LaTeX knitr document

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rnw

I'd like to print a few sentences in a knitr LaTeX doc (.Rnw), but only if some data exists.  Those sentences are mostly text, but with some R.

Example:

```
A chi-squared test of your observed sizes has a p-value of
\Sexpr{format(calculated_chisq$p.value,digits=3,scientific=F)}.
A p-value below 0.05 means you should be concerned that your
groups are broken.  The lower the p-value, the more worried you
should be.
```

I tried a chunk with `results='asis'`, but I think the chunk is interpreted as R.

I tried `print()` and `paste()` with R.  It's ugly, but it works. However, it puts extra text in that seems to correspond to the R prompt.

Is there a nice way to do this?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239835/inline-latex-code-inside-knitr-r-block) is related, but different.  [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333831/conditional-output-of-latex-based-on-r-parameter) is the same, but unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is closely related to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599993/can-knitr-dynamically-output-narrative-text-based-on-r-code-results-in-each-chun), but not duplicate I think: The accepted answer there translates into an ugly `\Sexp` monster with a condition inside. The code will be neither nice to read nor to write.

[My own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641628/2706569) there is also not applicable because 1) the `asis` engine does not allow for dynamic elements in the text and 2) because output from the `asis` gets a gray background color in RNW documents.

I suggest the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
  x <- rnorm(1)
@

The value of $x$ is \Sexpr{x}.

<<echo=FALSE, results = "asis">>=
  pattern <- "This will only be displayed if $x$ is positive. The value of $x$ is %.2f."
  if (x > 0) cat(sprintf(pattern, x))
@

\end{document}
```

The conditional output is easy to read and write (`pattern`) and the dynamic elements are inserted via `sprintf`.